Expo error: Uncaught Error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load all assets
When I start expo server using npx expo start -c server starts. My mobile and laptop are also connected on the same network. Now when I scan expo qr code through expo go in mobile, it displays error saying Uncaught error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load all assets sometimes displays timeout error. What's the issue? It's fresh project just installed everything.
In package.json file as per the documentation i've set
{
   .....
   "main": "expo-router/entry",
   .....
}

and project folder structure like
......
app
  _layout.jsx
assets
node_modules
.....
......


This may (or may not) be caused by the specific Android API Version of your Android Virtual Device. You could check and simply try the work-around posted here
